# What are the advantages of connecting uWSGI to NGinx using the uwsgi protocol?

Tags: nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

I have a [uWSGI service](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) running the Python [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) on an EC2 for some internal API. uWSGI listens on an internal port, that is blocked from the outside world.

The server runs NGinx to serve requests from the outside on ports 80/443, and proxies these requests to uWSGI using plain http proxy to the internal port.

[NGinx can also connect to uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html) using the [uwsgi protocol](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Protocol.html).

[image]

What are the advantages of using this protocol over plain http proxying?

Comment: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#why-not-simply-use-http-as-the-protocol

Comment: @AlexeyTen Great. Any idea what's the performance difference? Does it worth the effort?

Comment: What effort? Change proxy_pass to uwsgi_pass?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Not a big deal, but it requires some change in the uwsgi configuration. Doesn't worth it for a 10% performance change.

Comment: I doubt if it would even 0.1% change.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the research](http://brianmcdonnell.github.io/pycon_ie_2013/#/35) from PageFair you will have a boost in throughput with unix_socket+uwsgi over tcp+http. Its not x2, but still.

Numbers they provide indicate that `tcp_socket+http` gets 1247 queries/second, while `unix_socket+uwsgi` gets 1495 q/s.